# What is the quickest way to compare a C# Dictionary to a 'gold standard' Dictionary for equality?

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary

I have a known-good Dictionary, and at run time I need to create a new Dictionary and run a check to see if it has the same key-value pairs as the known-good Dictionary (potentially inserted in different orders), and take one path if it does and another if it doesn't. I don't necessarily need to serialize the entire known-good Dictionary (I could use a hash, for example), but I need some on-disk data that has enough information about the known-good Dictionary to allow for comparison, if not for recreation. What is the quickest way to do this? I can use a SortedDictionary, but the amount of time required to initialize and add values counts in the speed of this task.

Concrete example:

Consider a Dictionary`<String,List<String>>` that looks something like this (in no particular order, obviously):

```
{ {"key1", {"value1", "value2"} }, {"key2", {"value3", "value4"} } }
```

I create that Dictionary once and save some form of information about it on disk (a full serialization, a hash, whatever). Then, at runtime, I do the following:

```
Dictionary<String,List<String>> d1 = new Dictionary<String,List<String>> ();
Dictionary<String,List<String>> d2 = new Dictionary<String,List<String>> ();
Dictionary<String,List<String>> d3 = new Dictionary<String,List<String>> ();

String key11 = "key1";
String key12 = "key1";
String key13 = "key1";
String key21 = "key2";
String key22 = "key2";
String key23 = "key2";

List<String> value11 = new List<String> {"value1", "value2"};
List<String> value12 = new List<String> {"value1", "value2"};
List<String> value13 = new List<String> {"value1", "value2"};
List<String> value21 = new List<String> {"value3", "value4"};
List<String> value22 = new List<String> {"value3", "value4"};
List<String> value23 = new List<String> {"value3", "value5"};

dict1.add(key11, value11);
dict1.add(key21, value21);
dict2.add(key22, value22);
dict2.add(key12, value12);
dict3.add(key13, value13);
dict3.add(key23, value23);

dict1.compare(fileName); //Should return true
dict2.compare(fileName); //Should return true
dict3.compare(fileName); //Should return false
```

Again, if the overall time from startup to the return from compare() is quicker, I can change this code to use a SortedDictionary (or anything else) instead, but I can't guarantee ordering and I need some consistent comparison. compare() could load a serialization and iterate through the dictionaries, it could serialize the in-memory dictionary and compare the serialization to the file name, or it could do any number of other things.

Comment: Please confirm that you are seeking "value equality" as a comparison? The way the question is worded I believe this is the case, but I want to be certain.

Comment: When optimizing tasks like this it is helpful to be clear about what case you're optimizing for. Is the common case that needs to be optimized that the two dictionaries are the same, or that they are different? The reason I ask is because a common optimization technique is to do a cheap test that catches 99% of the "different" cases, and then an expensive test that confirms identity. Obviously that is not a good optimization if most of the time the dictionaries really are identical; the cheap test just slows you down.

Comment: Cos Callis: If, for each String-List<String> pair in the known-good dictionary, there is a String-List<String> pair in the dictionary to be checked that has the same valued String as the key and a List with the same valued Strings in the same order as the value, then I want true, otherwise false.

Comment: Eric Lippert: I expect that the Dictionaries will match in 90% of the cases, and if they don't match I have to perform an expensive, time-consuming startup.

Comment: Do we have a guarantee that the two dictionaries have the same policy for performing lookups? For example, is one a case-sensitive dictionary and one is case-insensitive? Having different policies can greatly complicate dictionary comparisons. (This is a problem I face frequently, given that the C# compiler does case-sensitive mappings from identifiers to members, and the VB compiler does case-insensitive mappings.)

Comment: We can guarantee that both dictionaries were created with the same version of C# running on the same .net (actually, Mono) platform.

Comment: @Shea: Sure, but that's not what I asked. You can create two dictionaries in the same process that have different policies; I do it every day. Do we know that the dictionaries have the same policy? It is not clear what it means to be equal when two dictionaries have different policies. For example, suppose one dictionary was "A"-->{"DEF"} and case-insensitive and the other was "a"-->{"DEF"}, "A"-->{"DEF"}, case-sensitive. Arguably those two dictionaries are the same; **they always agree on every query**. But they are of different sizes!

Comment: Eric Lippert: Then perhaps I don't understand all the details of how Dictionaries work. How do you make a Dictionary be case-insensitive?

Comment: @Shea Levy: Generic dictionaries in .NET can be constructed with a custom `IEqualityComparer<>` instance - which allows defines the semantics of key equality. If none is specified, the constructors use the default equality comparer for the type: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution one:  use set equality.

If the dictionaries are of different sizes, you know they are unequal.

If they are of the same size then build a mutable hash set of keys from one dictionary. Remove from it all the keys from the other dictionary. If you attempted to remove a key that wasn't there, then the key sets are unequal and you know which key was the problem.

Alternatively, build two hash sets and take their intersection; the resulting intersection should be the size of the original sets.

This takes O(n) time and O(n) space.

Once you know that the key sets are equal then go through all the keys one at a time, fetch the values, and do comparison of the values. Since the values are sequences, use SequenceEquals.  This takes O(n) time and O(1) space.

Solution two:  sort the keys

Again, if the dictionaries are of different size, you know they are unequal.

If they are of the same size, sort both sets of keys and do a SequenceEquals on them; if the sequences of keys are unequal then the dictionaries are unequal.

This takes O(n lg n) time and O(n) space.

If that succeeds, then again, go through the keys one at a time and compare the values.

Solution three:

Again, check the dictionaries to see if they are the same size.

If they are, then iterate over the keys of one dictionary and check to see if the key exists in the other dictionary. If it does not, then they are not equal. If it does, then check the corresponding values for equality.

This is O(n) in time and O(1) in space.

How to choose amongst these possible solutions? It depends on what the likely failure mode is, and whether you need to know what the missing or extra key is. If the likely failure mode is a bad key then it might be more performant to choose a solution that concentrates on finding the bad key first, and only checking for bad values if all the keys turn out to be OK. If the likely failure mode is a bad value, then the third solution is probably best, since it prioritizes checking values early.

Comment: +1 as always a thorough explanation.  Solution 3 was what I thought of first.

Answer (score 1):

Due to my comments on the accepted answer, here's a stricter check.

```
goodDictionary.Keys.All(k=>
    {
        List<string> otherVal;
        if(!testDictionary.TryGetValue(k,out otherVal))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return goodDictionary[k].SequenceEquals(otherVal);
    })
```

Comment: This has the same problem, just switched: the testDictionary can have more keys than the goodDictionary. The solution is a dictionary size check before any loop.

Comment: @Shea, yes, missed that case, but a definite improvement

Answer (score 0):

If you already have serialisation, then take the hash (I recommend SHA-1) of each serialised dictionary and then compare them.

Comment: Can I trust the serialization to be consistent?

Comment: Yes, if you write you own serialiser.  I would first sort all the keys of the dictionary and then serialise each key, value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a magic bullet here; you just need to do a lookup for each key pair:

```
public bool IsDictionaryAMatch(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionaryToCheck)
{
    foreach(var kvp in dictionaryToCheck)
    {
         // Do the Keys Match
         if(!goodDictionary.Exists(x => x.Key == kvp.Key))
             return false;

         foreach(var valueElement in kvp.Value)
         {
              // Do the Values in each list match
              if(!goodDictionary[kvp.Key].Exists(x => x == valueElement))
                  return false;
         }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best option (don't even need sorting this way). The one thing I would add is a check to see if the dictionaries have the same size before the foreach loop.

Comment: This will allow spurious entries in the good dictionary. Say key x of test dictionary contains 1,2,3,4 and key x of good dictionary contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 then this method will claim a match. Is this what was asked? It also does not enforce the order of the lists i.e. 1,2,3,4 will match 4,3,2,1.

Comment: spender: This is why I noted in my comment that I would add a check to see if the dictionaries have the same size. But the spirit of the answer seems the best option.

Comment: @Shea Levy, @Tejs: This code is trivially and obviously wrong. Suppose the dictionary to check is the empty dictionary. The loop is skipped and the function returns true. Even if you fix that, this code is *extremely inefficient* on large dictionaries or if the list values are long.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at some point you need to compare that each key has the same value, but before that you can do quick things, like checking to see how many keys each dictionary has, then checking that the list of keys match.  Those should be fairly quick, and if either of those tests fail you can abort the more expensive testing.

After that, you might be able to build separate lists of keys and then fire off a Paraells query to compare the actual values.